# Why Collections.EmptyMap.computeIfPresent() throws an exception intead of return null?

Tags: java, collections

The source code for the class is at https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java

According to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and [the default implementation for Map.computeIfPresent()](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Map.java#L1133), the method should return the new value associated with the specified key, or `null` if none. On the other hand, `EmptyMap` contain no element, then the `EmptyMap.computeIfPresent()` method should always return `null`.

So why does the implementation doesn't do that, but throw an exception instead?

I have tried to search for things about `EmptyMap.computeIfPresent()` but just found websites that write about the class or websites about the method, not telling me why they combine like that.

Comment: The javadoc also mentions the (optional) `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: from the javadoc you posted: "**Throws:** ... `UnsupportedOperationException` - if the put operation is not supported by this map (optional)"

Comment: So, is it just for consistency? Because in my op, returning null give me simpler flow in code. In my case, the emptyMap is the value from getOrDefault of a Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>, then the next step is to update value if present. Currently, I must check null/containsKey instead

Comment: If just check not null for the remapping function and return null, the map is still immutable

Answer (score 2):

computeIfPresent is a mutation. It inserts a value into the map. That map implementation is immutable.

Use getOrDefault.

Comment: In my case, the emptyMap is the value from getOrDefault of a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>`, then the next step is to update value if present. So the getOrDefault will not work here, must get and check null instead.

Answer (score 2):

This aspect is provided in the [documentation of the `Collection` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#unmodifiable):

> #### Unmodifiable Collections
>
> Certain methods of this interface are considered "destructive" and are called "mutator" methods in that they modify the group of objects contained within the collection on which they operate. They can be specified to throw `UnsupportedOperationException` if this collection implementation does not support the operation. Such methods should (but are not required to) throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` if the invocation would have no effect on the collection. For example, consider a collection that does not support the [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) operation. What will happen if the [`addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) method is invoked on this collection, with an empty collection as the argument? The addition of zero elements has no effect, so it is permissible for this collection simply to do nothing and not to throw an exception. However, it is recommended that such cases throw an exception unconditionally, as throwing only in certain cases can lead to programming errors.

A similar section is in the [`Map` interface’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#:%7E:text=The%20%22destructive%22%20methods,superimposed%22%20is%20empty.), but I think, it’s easier to understand if you have read the collection’s version first:

> The "destructive" methods contained in this interface, that is, the methods that modify the map on which they operate, are specified to throw `UnsupportedOperationException` if this map does not support the operation. If this is the case, these methods may, but are not required to, throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` if the invocation would have no effect on the map. For example, invoking the [`putAll(Map)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) method on an unmodifiable map may, but is not required to, throw the exception if the map whose mappings are to be "superimposed" is empty.

So it would be legal if the immutable empty map’s `computeIfPresent` method just returns `null`, but the general recommendation is that immutable collections should throw `UnsupportedOperationException` unconditionally, to help detecting errors.

Interestingly, `Collections.emptyMap().putAll(Collections.emptyMap());` does not throw an exception, which contradicts the recommendation, but does not violate the specification. In contrast, `Map.of().putAll(Map.of())` does throw an exception.

You can easily create your own always-empty map whose `computeIfPresent` won’t throw:

```java
/**
 * Does not throw on mutation methods if the call has no effect.
 */
final class AlwaysEmpty<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      public static <K,V> Map<K,V> instance() {
          return INSTANCE;
      }
    
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      static final AlwaysEmpty INSTANCE = new AlwaysEmpty();
    
      @Override
      public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
          return Collections.emptySet();
      }
}
```

which works with your intended use case like the following example

```java
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, m);
m.put(2, 3);

for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    map.getOrDefault(i, AlwaysEmpty.instance()).computeIfPresent(2, (k,v) -> v + 1);

System.out.println(map);
```